# Unable to redirect to iPhone, iPad using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone

I need to redirect mobile users to using respective device i.e. iPhone, iPad or Android.

For Android following javascript code redirects it properly.

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1)) {
  document.location = "http://www.cnn.com";
}
```

But i tried following code for iPhone:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('/iPhone/i') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('/iPod/i') != -1)) {
  document.location = "http://www.ebay.com";
}
```

or

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
  document.location = "http://www.ebay.com";
}
```

None of above code redirects website in iPhone or iPad.

I can't figure out why.

Please help or suggest.

Comment: Once I saw strange bug, when setting `location` directly causes a error. As a guess, I can suggest you writing `document.location.href = "http://www.ebay.com";`, but it's better to debug your code. At least with `alert`s and `try/catch`.

Comment: This isn't in the question but you could make it easy on yourself and use PHP `header('Location: http://google.com');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to use this Javascript to get redirection in Android, iOS and BB.

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function detectDevice()
{
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf("BlackBerry") >= 0) {
        window.location.replace("http://www.cnn.com");
    }
    else if (ua.indexOf("iPhone") >= 0){
        window.location.replace("http://www.ebay.com");
    }
    else if (ua.indexOf("iPad") >= 0){
        window.location.replace("http://www.ebay.com");
    }
    else if (ua.indexOf("Android") >= 0){
        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    }
}


</script>
<body onload="detectDevice()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it still doesn't redirects in iPhone.